# Why 123['toString'].length returns 1?

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(123['toString'].length);
```

why this code returns value: 1 ?

Any good explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in JavaScript the `length` of a function is the number of declared parameters it accepts. (*[**ECMAScript Standard Built-in Objects**](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects)*)

Your `123['toString']` returns the `toString` method of numbers which accepts a `radix` parameter (*see [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#syntax)*), so that is what 1 is for.

Comment: Although this is a correct answer: JavaScript does not support any _named_ arguments, only positional ones.

Comment: But the radix argument is optional.

Answer (score 2):

It's the expected number of parameters of the `toString` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

The statement is interpreted like this:

```
123  => number
['toString'] => function toString of number
.length => length property of the function
```

Comment: [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) expects 2 but `(123).toLocaleString.length` returns 0.

Comment: As `toLocaleString` is only an alias for `NumberFormat` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) I guess that a proxy implementaion like this is used with variadict arguments:  https://jsfiddle.net/d57h2Lb6/